# Scrapy downloading large files

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python and scrapy. Recently I tried to crawl a video website which has over 3,000 pages, and each page contains 20 videos. I am using `scrapy` to fetch urls (including source of videos and next page) and `requests` to download the videos. The problem is, the script runs without any error, but the crawling speed is rather slow (about 4pages/min). I guess it's because scrapy is blocking next request, or pausing the download process, as a video is being downloaded? If so, is there any way I can improve the speed of scrapy instead of writing another script using `multithreading`? Here're my scripts:

setting.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'video'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['video.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'video.spiders'

LOG_LEVEL= 'DEBUG'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS= 'video.custom_filters.ViewKeyFilter'

DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 1

ITEM_PIPELINES= {'video.pipelines.VideoPipeline': 1,
                 'video.pipelines.Duplicates_Pipeline':300}

FILES_STORE= '/root/OneDrive/HDvideo'
```

custom_filters.py

```
class ViewKeyFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

def __init__(self,path=None,debug=False):
    self.urls_seen = set()
    RFPDupeFilter.__init__(self,path,debug)

def request_seen(self, request):
    if 'viewkey=' in request.url:
        pattern = re.compile(r'viewkey=(\w*)')
        if pattern.search(request.url).group(1) in self.urls_seen:
            return True
        else:
            self.urls_seen.add(request.url)
```

spider.py

```
class videoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'video'

def start_requests(self):
    url = "http://video.com/v.php?next=watch&page=1"
    yield Request(url,callback=self.parse,headers=headers,dont_filter=True)


def parse(self, response):
    doc = HTML(html=response.text)
    if doc.find('a:contains(">")'):
        yield Request('http://video.com/v.php' + doc.find('a:contains(">")')[0].attrs['href'],
                      callback=self.parse, headers=headers,dont_filter=True)
    for video_box in doc.find('div.listchannel'):
        title = video_box.find('a[target="blank"]')[0].find('img')[0].attrs['title']
        if not any(keyword in title for keyword in filterTitle):
            SDURL = video_box.find('a[target="blank"]')[0].attrs['href']
            if 'viewkey=' in SDURL:
                if video_box.find('div.hd-video'):
                    vkey = pattern.search(SDURL).group(1)  # Handling HD videos
                    yield Request('http://video.com/video_hd.php?viewkey={}'.format(vkey),
                                  callback=self.parse_videoPage, headers=headers, cookies=cookies[random.randint(0,len(dummy_cookie) -1)])
                else:
                    yield Request(SDURL,callback=self.parse_videoPage,
                                  headers=headers)  

def parse_videoPage(self,response):
    if 'video_missing' not in response.url:
        doc = HTML(html=response.text)
        title = doc.find('#video-title')[0].text
        src = doc.find('source')[0].attrs['src']
        item = VideoItem()
        item['title'] = title
        item['src'] = src
        item['vkey'] = pattern.search(response.url).group(1)
        self.logger.info('Return item. Title:{} src:{}'.format(title,src))
        yield item
```

pipelines.py

```
 class VideoPipeline(MediaPipeline):


    def process_item(self, item,spider):
        if item['src']:
            try:
                r =requests.get(item['src'],stream=True,timeout=5,headers=headers)
                log.logger.info('Downloading video: {}'.format(item['title']))
                with open('/root/OneDrive/HDvideo/' + item['title'] + '.mp4','wb') as f:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        if chunk:
                            f.write(chunk)
                log.logger.info('Downloaded video: {}'.format(item['title']))
            except:
                log.logger.exception('Something bad happened: ')
            finally:
                return


class Duplicates_Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vkeys_seen = set()

    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        if item is not None:
            if item['vkey'] in self.vkeys_seen:
                raise DropItem('Duplicate item found: {}'.format(item))
            else:
                self.vkeys_seen.add(item['vkey'])
                return item
```

Videos will be saved to `/root/OneDrive/`, it's a directory mounted on my Vultr VPS with `rclone`. Sorry for my English. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS (I think the default is 16) you could try altering that value. Sometimes lowering it can provide a better speed overall.

Comment: Hello, @Tony Thanks for the quick reply. I've already tried exactly what you said including CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN before, but the log file shows scrapy will visit the same page several times once concurrent values are increased. I think the problem comes from `pipelines.py`?

Comment: If you have 20 videos per page, and 16 concurrent connections, you will get a low page count as, depending on the size of the video files, you need to download 20 videos before the next page is requested. You say the crawling speed is slow but pages/min is not the best measure. How long does it take you to download 1 video in your browser, and what's your internet connection speed?

Comment: Hi, @Tony, I've just tested on my VPS. You're right, the target website does have limitation of download speed, and the maximum I can get is around 600KB/s. But I've wrote a simple script before using`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, and the script gives me 22GB videos in 2 hours. So I guess scrapy is downloading the videos one by one? I think it would be better crawling big sites with a framework, as the website keeps updating.

Comment: The site could also be throttling your download if it recognises your connection as a bot. Do you get any 502 errors in your logs?

Comment: Hi, @Tony, actually the website is kind of vulnerable. I am using several cookies and I randomize the `X-Forwarded-For`  in headers, which seems to keep me under the radar. I've been downloading videos from the same site for a week and the log file show no error.

Comment: “but the log file shows scrapy will visit the same page several times once concurrent values are increased”. That sounds weird. Could you ellaborate?